# Make regex match dotfiles accurately

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

So I have hit the limit of my regex abilities with this. I have here a python regex to match a file path or file uri with named capture groups for the various parts. It seems to be working file, except on dotfiles.

```
MATCH_PATH = re.compile(
    r"^(?P<uri>file://)?" +             # optional file uri
    r"(?P<path>(?:/?[A-Z]{1}:)?" +      # start of path capture, optional windows top-level directory
    r"[\\/]?" +                         # optional start separator
    r"(?:[\w \-\.]+[\\/])+)" +          # path
    r"(?P<filename>[\w \-]+)?" +        # optional filename
    r"\.?(?P<extension>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?$" # extension optional
)
```

I can make it match dotfiles by [removing the optional qualifier `?`](https://regex101.com/r/j1K5k2/2) after the `.` in the extension portion, but then it can't match files without an extension (e.g. makefile) nor directories. I tried placing a [non-capturing group around the dot and the extension group with the optional qualifier](https://regex101.com/r/j1K5k2/1), that didn't work: the extension gets grouped with the filename. Can I tweak this to match the extension and name correctly in all cases while still matching directories?

Examples inputs that should be matched:

```
/foo/bar.txt
/foo/bar/
/foo/makefile
./foo.txt
/foo/._bar.txt
foo/bar.txt
D:\foo\bar.m3u
file:///var/www/html/index.html
file:///C:/users/me/My Documents/index.html
```

#### UPDATE

Also needs to correctly match

```
/foo/bar.tar.gz
/foo/._bar.tar.gz
```

With the extension being `tar.gz` and names being `bar` and `._bar` respectively. Also please let me know if this is too complex for regex and I can write procedural code to split and process instead.

Comment: You are missing the possible . (dot) in the filename group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may very well use named captured groups in a lookahead, like so:

```
^
(?P<uri>file://)?
(?P<path>(?:/?[A-Z]{1}:)?           # start of path capture, optional windows top-level directory
[\\/]?                              # optional start separator
(?:[-. \w]+[\\/])+)                 # path
(?P<filename>\.?[^.]+?(?=\.(?P<extension>.+$)|$))?
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/8zRU4S/3/).

---

Only thing I changed, is the group `filename`:

```
(?P<filename>\.?[^.]+?(?=\.(?P<extension>.+$)|$))
```

It uses a lazy dot-star with a positive lookahead, looking either for `.some_extension` (then saving it to `extension`) or the end of the line.

Comment: This is nice but fails on e.g. `/foo/bar.tar.gz`, I have updated the question to reflect this requirement.

Comment: You will then need to define which file extensions can occur - for a regex engine `.bar.txt` as in `_bar.bar.txt` is the same as `.tar.gz` in `bar.tar.gz`.

Comment: It could be anything, and we may be getting out of the realm of what regexes can do (in which case I'll parse it out by hand). Basically I want everything up to the first dot to be the name (unless the first character is a dot, i.e. a dotfile) and everything thereafter to be the extension.

Comment: So `foo/bar.tar.gz` would have a name of `bar` and an extension of `tar.gz` and `foo/._bar.tar.gz` would have a name of `._bar` and an extension of `tar.gz`.

Comment: @JaredSmith: See the updated answer and demo, use a negated class then.

Comment: Close enough. Your new example fails on the case where its a directory with no file (e.g. "/foo/bar/") but adding a quantifier `?` to the end of that grouping fixes it. Thanks!

Comment: @JaredSmith: Done that as well.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to clean it up a bit and get the regex to match all of your sample data. [Here](https://regex101.com/r/DikDxF/3) is there testing environment so you can see it is working with the different capturing groups.

```
^(?P<uri>file:\/\/\/)?
(?P<path>(?:\/|\\|\.)?(?:[A-Z]:(?:\/|\\))?(?:[\w \-\.]+[\/\\])+)
(?P<file>\.?[\_\w ]+)?
(?P<extension>\.[\w\d]+)?$
```

I think the main issue with the one you have is that you aren't including the possibility of the preceding `.` in the `file` capturing group. To remedy that, I added it as an optional preceding `.` with the `file` group and worked around that.

The other small change I made was including the extension's preceding `.` in the the `extension` group, but that can be changed if you want.

Comment: Hmm, try now. I thought I saved it before.

Comment: There are a couple of flaws here, especially does the character class `\w` include `\d`. Additionally, forward slashes do not need to be escaped in `Python`. Dots or minus signs do not need to be escaped in a character class either. All in one: https://regex101.com/r/DikDxF/4

Comment: There are a few problems with this... it captures the dot in the extension which I don't want, it adds an extra slash to the file uri, and the `\w` in the extension allows underscores unlike my original grouping. Still, +1 for a solid effort.