# Regex matching with end dollar sign on URL pattern in python

Tags: python, regex, regex-greedy

Here's ther scenario, I'd like to extract secondary path in URL, so the following URL should all return 'a-c-d'

```
/opportunity/a-c-d
/opportunity/a-c-d/
/opportunity/a-c-d/123/456/
/opportunity/a-c-d/?x=1
/opportunity/a-c-d?x=1
```

My code snippet is as follows:

```
m = re.match("^/opportunity/([^/]+)[\?|/|$]", "/opportunity/a-c-d")
if m:
    print m.group(1)
```

It works for all possible URLs above EXCEPT the first one `/opportunity/a-c-d`. Could anyone help explain the reason and rectify my regex please? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why do you have `|` twice inside the `[]`? There's no reason to list the same character multiple times in a character set.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make regex match dotfiles accurately](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42913533/make-regex-match-dotfiles-accurately)

Comment: Your regular expression requires the second component of the URL to be followed by `?`, `|`, `/`, or `$`. None of them is after `a-c-d` in the first URL.

Comment: It looks like you don't understand the difference between `[` and `(` in regular expressions -- `[\?|/|$]` should be `(\?|/|$)`

Comment: And after changing, `m = re.match("^/opportunity/([^/]+)(\?|/|$)", "/opportunity/a-scholarship-at-oncampus-reading-art-design?123")` will be wrong @Barmar

Comment: Why is it wrong? What does it return, what should it return instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$` in your regex is matching the literal '$' character, not the end of line character. Instead, you probably want this:

```
m = re.match(r"^/opportunity/([^/?]+)\/?\??", "/opportunity/a-c-d")
if m:
    print m.group(1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't do this. Use the [urlparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlsplit) module instead.

Here is some test code:

```
from urlparse import urlparse

urls = [
  '/opportunity/a-c-d',
  '/opportunity/a-c-d/',
  '/opportunity/a-c-d/123/456/',
  '/opportunity/a-c-d/?x=1',
  '/opportunity/a-c-d?x=1',
]

def secondary(url):
  try:
    return urlparse(url).path.split('/')[2]
  except IndexError:
    return None

for url in urls:
  print '{0:30s} => {1}'.format(url, secondary(url))
```

and here is the output

```
/opportunity/a-c-d             => a-c-d
/opportunity/a-c-d/            => a-c-d
/opportunity/a-c-d/123/456/    => a-c-d
/opportunity/a-c-d/?x=1        => a-c-d
/opportunity/a-c-d?x=1         => a-c-d
```

Comment: Forget my answer, this is more correct. URL parsing is a solved problem that regexes shouldn't be used for.

Comment: Just adding that in Python 3 the library has been rename, so you will need to import  `from urllib.parse import urlparse`

Answer (score 1):

Alternative patterns should be inside `()`, not `[]`, which is for matching specific characters.

You should also use a raw string, so that escape sequences will be sent literally to the `re` module, not get interpreted in the Python string.

```
m = re.match(r"^/opportunity/([^/]+)(\?|/|$])", "/opportunity/a-c-d")
```

or

```
m = re.match(r"^/opportunity/([^/]+)([?/]|$])", "/opportunity/a-c-d")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use () to include all you need.

```
[re.sub(r'.*(\w+-\w+-\w+).*',r'\1',x) for x in urls]
```